# How install Ubuntu 16.04 on notebook with Windows 10 and have space for Windows

Tags: software-installation

I have a notebook with Windows 10; the hard drive has 745 gigs. I would like to have 200 gigs for Ubuntu 16.04, the rest for Windows. When I try to install Ubuntu 16.04 it looks like Windows will only get 500 megs, which is not enough.
How do I do that, this installation is very very confusing.
BR,
Lloyd

Answer (score 0):

In your Ubuntu Live CD, you should use the program gparted to shrink your Windows partition (right-click your Windows partition and click resize/move) down to the desired size and once you have some unallocated space make a new partition thats ext4 (or whatever your are going to use) afterwards go into the installer and when it asks where to install Ubuntu, click Something else, select your new ext4 partition and hit change, set its mount point to / after that you should just click install.

Answer (score 0):

Same here - added Ubuntu (originally 14.x now 16.04) to Windows where Windows is now 10.

I used gparted to format the drive.

http://gparted.org/

Download gparted image, burn onto a DVD and then boot from that.  You probably have a UEFI ROM so you might have to fiddle with its settings to boot from the DVD.

I'd note also that I had to switch the boot manager to GRUB.  A new Ubuntu install these days may make GRUB the default in which case you won't have to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying

> When I try to install Ubuntu 16.04 it looks like Windows will only get 500 megs, which is not enough

I am assuming that you know that you can use the files and all the content of the other 500 GB part of the HDD while using ubuntu but you won't be able to use the 200 GB of HDD while using windows

Now answering to your Question While using windows go to the Device manager and shrink your largest partition such that 200 GB of HDD space is  unalloted.
Now Boot using your ubuntu bootable drive and you will be able to see an option install ubuntu side by side windows.There is a 1% probablity that option doesn't occur. Don't panic in that case just shutdown your computer and get back to this forum